# How to convert UTC Date to New Zeeland time zone in XSLT1.0?

Tags: date, timezone, xslt-1.0, utc

I am trying to change a date from UTC format to the New Zeeland time zone. I was able to find a working solution, as shown in the following example:

`xsl:value-of select="xs:dateTime('2002-12-24T12:00:12Z')+xs:dayTimeDuration('PT12H')"`

Unfortunately, the tool I am using to generate this does not support XSLT 2.0. Also, changing the timezone on the system is not a possibility; the current date on the system will still be in UTC.

Is there any other way of achieving this with XSLT 1.0?

Thanks

Comment: I believe there should be. What did your search bring up?

Comment: That presumes NZ is fixed to UTC+12.  It's not.  It also uses UTC+13 for part of the year.  https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/new-zealand/auckland